# Subset dataframe by factor variable

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

Newbie here. I'm sure this is easy and have been answered before but I've been more than an hour now looking for the answer and can't find it.

I have a dataframe with 3 variables:

```
> str(statement)
'data.frame':   16464206 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ statement_type_cd: Factor w/ 428 levels "A00001","A00002"...
 $ statement_text   : Factor w/ 9894526 levels...
 $ serial_no        : int  60146682 60149828 70011210...
```

I'd like to extract the `statement_text` observations that matches the `statement_type_cd` observations `GSXXXX` being X any number.

In other words, how do I subset the dataframe by any observation that begins with `GS` in the `statement_type_cd` variable?

Thanks :)

Comment: Use `substr` to extract the first 2 letters and check if they are equal to "GS".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grepl` to create a logical vector by matching the pattern 'GS' from the start (`^`) of the string and use it to `subset` the dataset

```
statementsub <- subset(statement, grepl("^GS", statement_type_cd))
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
statementsub <- statement %>%
                    filter(grepl("^GS", statement_type_cd))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer akrun! That worked perfectly! It was funny, I was reading about [regular expressions](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) when I saw your answer :)